# Why my site is considered "No HSTS header is present on the response"

Tags: hsts

I am supporting a website

https://www.somesite.com

and I have followed all the requirements set at

https://hstspreload.appspot.com

However when I entered somesite.com to check status and eligibility, I got errors:

```
Error: No HSTS header
Response error: No HSTS header is present on the response.
```

Comment: BTW: Your http->https redirection is a bit brittle, if you do not specify a host header it uses an internal IP.

Comment: eckes, thanks for chiming in! "if you do not specify a host header it uses an internal IP" ---> how can I do this? Any pointer? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HSTS header is set on https://www.somesite.com/ but not on https://somesite.com/ which is a requirement:

> Serve an HSTS header on the base domain for HTTPS requests

Btw as you don't yet have this on your base domain yet I would **STRONGLY** encourage you to run with it set there for a bit first before submitting for preload in case you have any http only other subdomains (e.g. http://blog.somesite.com or http://intranet.somesite.com) as they will stop working once preloaded as they will now also require https.

Comment: One of the requirements for preloading is you must set this on the base domain (https://allcounted.com) **as well**. You must have separate server config for that to redirect and that config is not setting the header. Yes you are right that only the first connection is at risk (which preload is designed to fix). However preloading can be dangerous since it's basically impossible to reverse. I personally do not recommend it except for very high risk sites as [I've blogged here](https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/dangerous-web-security-features/)).

Comment: Thanks sooooooooo much for your clear and detailed explanation!

Comment: Thanks for the info here ! Interesting